# Use Resources in MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, resources, media-player

I just want to play a mp3-file on a button click event.

I made a folder called 'raw' in 'res' and I put the audio files into this folder.

The mp3 file I want to play is called 'miau'

Now I've written this:

```
MediaPlayer sound = new MediaPlayer();
sound.setDataSource(res.raw.miau);
```

Error Message:

> res.raw.miau cannot be resolved to a variable

But it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Comment: I made it with public MediaPlayer miau = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.miau); but if i run the application, there comes a message 'Unfortunately, <AppName> has stopped.'

Comment: Please provide a logcat output. And, please update the question with your changed code. One should understand what you're doing wrong and what's going on, before reading additional comments by you.